# Park and Ride Newcastle

Tags: driving, england, day-trips

I'm planning a day visit to Newcastle (upon Tyne), arriving from the south. I want to arrive on a Saturday around 10AM, park my car, travel into the city center using public transport, and leave around 6PM.

Although I found many park and rides on the Newcastle council web site, the information on parking cost, allowable length of stay, busy-ness of the location and availability of space on my planned day and time is sadly disappointing. The last thing I want is to arrive at a destination, find it not possible to park and having to figure something out while driving.

I am looking for a park and ride with plenty of spaces on a Saturday morning, good regular public transport to the city center, no chance of being crazy busy (i.e. a football stadium or shopping center) and preferably approachable from the south without driving through the city.

For reference I often use the Trumpington Park and Ride in Cambridge and am looking for something exactly like that.

Comment: Note that Newcastle also has a metro light rail system. See [Metro Park and Ride stations](https://www.nexus.org.uk/metro-park-and-ride-stations) which says *Park for only £1.20 a day at Metro Park and Ride stations.  Parking is free on Sundays at the Metro station car parks listed*.

Comment: @Weather yes, thanks for that, but I am looking for more information around convenience/availability/busy-ness of these locations for my journey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find anything exactly similar to the Trumpington P&R; the closest analogue is parking at the MetroCentre in Gateshead, close to the MetroCentre railway station, with trains to Newcastle every 20 mins. Parking is free during the shopping centre's opening hours (https://themetrocentre.co.uk/centre-information/services-at-metrocentre/free-parking). With 10k parking spaces, there no chance of it being completely full!

Another option is to park for £7 at the Newcastle main railway station. With 454 spaces, I'm pretty sure you'll be able to park your car on Saturday. This car park is within walking distance of the city centre, so no public transport needed.

Comment: Shopping centre parking may have enough capacity on a December Saturday, but that doesn't mean the access does. Queues to get out can be very long in many places